# Is it possible to increase the efficiency of a propelled vehicle by extracting and using the energy from its own suspension system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, energy-conservation

If there is a propelled vehicle and it has a passive suspension system (Springs for example):
Is it possible to increase the efficiency of the system "propelled vehicle" by extracting energy from the suspension system with a recuperation device?

To give an example:
Lets assume a car with an electric motor and with springs as a suspension system. These springs should be connected with linear generators. Can I increase the efficiency of the car by extracting electrical power with the linear generators and by transmitting this energy to the electric motor?
Can I use the suspension system as a way of generating electrical power in a sense of "charging" the car batterie?

Many thanks in advance!

If I should edit my post in any way, please let me know, it's my first post here.

Comment: I would think that the added weight from the "energy harvesting system" would lower the vehicle efficiency a bit, largely defeating the small increase in efficiency from such a system.

Comment: Why would it lower the efficiency of the vehicle? The efficiency is related to its weight and not to the total consuption. But I agree that it would most likely not make sense economically.

Comment: Energy consumption in an automobile is strongly affected by total vehicle weight, as it takes more energy to accelerate a heavy vehicle, and rolling resistance of tires increases as weight increases.  That is why auto manufacturers design autos with plastic and light weight components.

Answer (score 0):

No, where's why.

We imagine the simplest form of "bump capture": we imagine a tire on a car to be a cogged gearwheel with pointed teeth on it. when the cogwheel rolls into a pothole, the leading edge of the wheel rolls into the pothole and engages the lip of the pothole, so that as the wheel rolls across and down into the pothole, there is a force applied to the teeth on the wheel by the lip of the pothole which generates a torque which urges the wheel to rotate in its direction of travel.

But that force also points in a direction opposite to the car's direction of linear movement and thereby acts to slow the car down.

In this scenario, the effects cancel and this means that you cannot "harvest" suspension travel to produce a net force which assists the car in its forward motion.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite a good visualization with the gearwheel and this answers my questions about the example of the car. How would you explain it in a more general term for any propelled vehicle in a linear motion which has a suspension system which dampens the movement in a right angle along the direction of travel? Like spacecrafts and ships with hydraulic suspension systems. Is it the same principle?

Comment: Not sure, let me think on this for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is "theoretically" possible. The suspension system of a car works by dissipating the "energy" of the shock through shock absorbers .
To quote wikipedia  '

> It does this by converting the kinetic energy of the shock into
> another form of energy (typically heat) which is then dissipated. Most
> shock absorbers are a form of *dashpot* (a damper which resists motion
> via viscous friction).

So, theoretically that energy could be somehow stored and harvested. But obviously, the engineering challenges and the state of the current technology mean that this is not a feasible option. The economics of it would not work.

But there is nothing preventing this theoretically speaking. Maybe, two hundred years from now, automobile technology would have advanced to such a level as to be able to utilise this.
An interesting technology along similar lines is the Kinetic Energy Recovery System ( KERS ) used in Formula 1 cars. It uses the energy that would have been dissipated as heat by the braking system , and stores it , so as to use it later for acceleration. 50 years ago, that might have sounded just as outlandish

Comment: Ah, okay, Thanks! But if I take the energy out of a perfect suspension system it wouldn't get back into its previous position. So if a suspension system dissipates heat, it constantly loses energy which it should save for getting into its previous place. So where does the system get the additional energy from? Is it some external factor or does it come from the propulsion system?

Comment: I dont understand exactly what you mean . Are you talking about the KERS system ?